# How to read multiple files(pdfs) from mapr volume performs OCR and dump in a mapr volume using kubernetes jobs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, mapr

'''
apiVersion: batch/v1

kind: Job

metadata:

name: parallel-job

namespace:

spec:

completions: 6 # number of times to run

parallelism: 2 # number of pods that can run in parallel

backoffLimit: 6 # number of retries before throwing error

activeDeadlineSeconds: 10 # time to allow job to run

template:

```
metadata:

  labels:

    app: kubernetes-series

    tier: job

spec:

  restartPolicy: OnFailure

  containers:

    - name: job-fibonacci-2

      image: 

      args:

      - sleep

      - "1000000"

      resources:

        requests:

          memory: 500M

          cpu: 100

      volumeMounts:

      - name: 

        mountPath: 

      name: maprvolume

    volumes:

    - name: maprvolume

      persistentVolumeClaim:

        claimName: pvc-mapr
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link and update your question accordingly. Start formatting your code for example.

Comment: Actually providing a bit of background about the task and then asking a coherent question that can be answered would help a lot.